OpenOCD Halting at 0xfffffffe - STM32F030C8TX_FLASH Debugging Problems
I'm trying to debug my STM32F030C8TX_FLASH microcontroller using OpenOCD and CLion, but I'm encountering a persistent issue. OpenOCD seems to be initializing the device correctly, but it's getting repeatedly halted at the address 0xfffffffe without any explicit breakpoints set in my code. This is leading to debugging issues, and I'm unable to progress.
Here's the OpenOCD output I'm getting:
[Insert OpenOCD output here - including the lines about halting at 0xfffffffe]

Here is complete output -> http://notepad.link/share/Xer4WpMbUXXeeSVcqPQo
My configuration file (board/stm32f0discovery.cfg):
# OpenOCD Configuration for STM32F0 Discovery
source [find interface/stlink.cfg]
set WORKAREASIZE 0x20000
transport select hla_swd
source [find target/stm32f0x.cfg]

adapter speed 4000 
set _SWD_CLOCK 4000 
reset_config srst_open_drain 


Also this is stm32f0x.cfg file
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later

# script for stm32f0x family

#
# stm32 devices support SWD transports only.
#
source [find target/swj-dp.tcl]
source [find mem_helper.tcl]

if { [info exists CHIPNAME] } {
   set _CHIPNAME $CHIPNAME
} else {
   set _CHIPNAME stm32f0x
}

set _ENDIAN little

# Work-area is a space in RAM used for flash programming
# By default use 4kB
if { [info exists WORKAREASIZE] } {
   set _WORKAREASIZE $WORKAREASIZE
} else {
   set _WORKAREASIZE 0x1000
}

# Allow overriding the Flash bank size
if { [info exists FLASH_SIZE] } {
    set _FLASH_SIZE $FLASH_SIZE
} else {
    # autodetect size
    set _FLASH_SIZE 0
}

#jtag scan chain
if { [info exists CPUTAPID] } {
   set _CPUTAPID $CPUTAPID
} else {
  # See STM Document RM0091
  # Section 29.5.3
   set _CPUTAPID 0x0bb11477
}

swj_newdap $_CHIPNAME cpu -irlen 4 -ircapture 0x1 -irmask 0xf -expected-id $_CPUTAPID
dap create $_CHIPNAME.dap -chain-position $_CHIPNAME.cpu

set _TARGETNAME $_CHIPNAME.cpu
target create $_TARGETNAME cortex_m -endian $_ENDIAN -dap $_CHIPNAME.dap

$_TARGETNAME configure -work-area-phys 0x20000000 -work-area-size $_WORKAREASIZE -work-area-backup 0

# flash size will be probed
set _FLASHNAME $_CHIPNAME.flash
flash bank $_FLASHNAME stm32f1x 0x08000000 $_FLASH_SIZE 0 0 $_TARGETNAME

# adapter speed should be <= F_CPU/6. F_CPU after reset is 8MHz, so use F_JTAG = 1MHz
adapter speed 1000

adapter srst delay 100

reset_config srst_nogate

if {![using_hla]} {
   # if srst is not fitted use SYSRESETREQ to
   # perform a soft reset
   cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
}

proc stm32f0x_default_reset_start {} {
    # Reset clock is HSI (8 MHz)
    adapter speed 1000
}

proc stm32f0x_default_examine_end {} {
    # Enable debug during low power modes (uses more power)
    mmw 0x40015804 0x00000006 0 ;# DBGMCU_CR |= DBG_STANDBY | DBG_STOP

    # Stop watchdog counters during halt
    mmw 0x40015808 0x00001800 0 ;# DBGMCU_APB1_FZ |= DBG_IWDG_STOP | DBG_WWDG_STOP
}

proc stm32f0x_default_reset_init {} {
    # Configure PLL to boost clock to HSI x 6 (48 MHz)
    mww 0x40021004 0x00100000   ;# RCC_CFGR = PLLMUL[2]
    mmw 0x40021000 0x01000000 0 ;# RCC_CR[31:16] |= PLLON
    mww 0x40022000 0x00000011   ;# FLASH_ACR = PRFTBE | LATENCY[0]
    sleep 10                    ;# Wait for PLL to lock
    mmw 0x40021004 0x00000002 0 ;# RCC_CFGR |= SW[1]

    # Boost JTAG frequency
    adapter speed 8000
}

# Default hooks
$_TARGETNAME configure -event examine-end { stm32f0x_default_examine_end }
$_TARGETNAME configure -event reset-start { stm32f0x_default_reset_start }
$_TARGETNAME configure -event reset-init { stm32f0x_default_reset_init }

I've tried the following:

Changing GDB Ports:  I've adjusted the GDB port in OpenOCD to avoid conflicts, but the issue persists.
Checking for Breakpoints:  I've double-checked my code to ensure there are no breakpoints set.
Reviewing OpenOCD Configuration:  I've verified the configuration file, including the reset_config setting.
Restarting OpenOCD:  I've restarted OpenOCD.
Updating Drivers: I have the latest ST-Link V2 drivers.

What could be causing this unexpected halting behavior at 0xfffffffe? Is there a problem with my OpenOCD configuration, my code, or perhaps a hardware issue?

Program counter values of 0xFFFFFFxx have special meanings, they are basically ARM core error codes. Clearly, something in the executed code goes very wrong.
